# Should I make Joomla return a 404 error when page is not found for SEO purposes?

Tags: redirect, joomla, http-status-code-404

I'm using Joomla 2.5 and I have edited the error.php to include the following PHP code:

```
if (($this->error->getCode()) == '404') {
header('Location: /404');
exit;
}
```

This is if someone links to domain.com/SomethingBogus they don't get the standard Joomla page for 404 error. So I created an Article called 404 and put it in a hidden menu and now when that happens it displays the information such as "Sorry you are having a problem...report this here...etc".

But I did a 'wget' on this and it returns a 200 status which means the page is OK. I've been told that I should still return a 404 error, otherwise SEO wise you get punished by Google.com. OK, I understand that but how do I do both? If so, how do I do that because I don't believe you can use a header of 404 not found error and also redirect it to an information page using:

```
<?php 
if ($this->error->getcode() == '404') {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
} ?>
```

I have seen web pages which says something is not found which may be returning a 404 error and then waits 5 seconds and then does the redirect. If that is the answer how do I do that in Joomla? Thanks!

Comment: Correct, if you have a page loading successfully then it will not return a 404 nor should it.  And you can't send a http status after the page has loaded.  Joomla has its built in system for handling 404s, which is the error.php page. What you should do is customize that page to contain whatever it is that you would like the redirected to to return. Whatever content it is you have on your hidden page, just replicate it on the error.php page. You can make that page as complex as you would like it to be.

Comment: @Elin I'm using the error.php. So you are saying, I can have that message such as "Sorry that page isn't found...etc" and it will display this and also return a 404 not found error?

Comment: @Elin I was hoping to have this page not look like the generic 404 Not Found page from Joomla, but make look like part of the rest of the website using the Joomla template. Can that still easily be achieved and return a 404 error message? Thanks!

Comment: Of course, that's why you have the error.php file in your template. You should make that look exactly how you want tit to look. For example usually I put the navigation from the site, some common links and a search box. You can look at the core templates to see examples of how to make a custom page.